# PHP mysql_query("SELECT * FROM require) fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, function

I'm developing an android app, which gets data from an mysql-database from server. I'm hosting a local server mysql-database and want to get all data from a table named "`require`".

In my PHP script I'm doing the following:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  mysql_select_db("meinstudiumosdatabase");
  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM require");
  echo mysql_error();


  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
      $output[] = $row;
  }

  print(json_encode($output));
  mysql_close();
?>
```

The `mysql_query` fails with the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'require' at line 1.

Where is the problem? 
The require table has two integer columns, nothing special.
I have 6 other tables where this script works fine.
Hope you can help.

---

**`EDIT:`**
Changed title, so people who used "`require`" as tablename find this easier.

Greetings 
Kai

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`require` is a [`reserved keyword`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) in MySQL and you need to enclose it in backticks !

Like this..

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `require`");
```

Also, Stop using the deprecated database API [`mysql_*` functions]. Instead switch to **`PDO`** or **`MySQLi`**.

Comment: +1 for the fastest to answer :)

Comment: A better idea is to avoid reserved words altogether!

Answer (score 1):

Enclose require with backticks. The reason your query fail is that require is a reserved word.